# Starting tensor indices at 0

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Some time ago I wrote a package for tensor calculus in General Relativity. In order to make it easily accessible  for others it should be slightly modified.

There are functions like i.e. Christoffel for calculation of Christoffel symbol :

```
Christoffel[g_, xx_] := 
    Block[{ig, res, n}, 
           n = 4;
           ig = Simplify[Inverse[g]]; 
           res = Table[(1/2)*Sum[ig[[i,s]]*(-D[g[[j,k]], xx[[s]]] + D[g[[j,s]], xx[[k]]] 
                             + D[g[[s,k]], xx[[j]]]), {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}];
       res
     ]
```

where g and xx are metric tensor and coordinates respectively, which I define in a Mathematica session after uploading the package in a straightforward way putting for example an ansatz for a static spherically symmetric spacetime : 
  [image: metric]
 This way involves drawbacks since index ranges are `{1, 2, 3, 4}`  while the common practice in relativistic physics suggests to put `{0, 1, 2, 3}` where 0 stands for timelike coordinate, and `{1, 2, 3}` stand for spacelike ones.
   To ilustrate the problem let's define a table where indices start from 0 , i.e.

```
V = Table[i - j, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}] 
{{0, -1, -2, -3}, {1, 0, -1, -2}, {2, 1, 0, -1}, {3, 2, 1, 0}}
```

but when I evaluate 
 `V[[0, 0]]` 
I get   `Symbol` - the head of V,
  while for  `V[[1, 2]]` I get `-1` as it should be.

**My questions are :**

1. How could I redefine V in order be able to evaluate "table" component `[0, 0]` ?
2. What would be the most convenient way to introduce matrix g with its indices starting at 0?
3. Since I have to give up using `Part` to access tensor components `0,0`
   how to introduce in a package a freedom of choice of index ranges of other objects like Christoffel (let's say by default index ranges - `{0, 1, 2, 3}` or if one prefers - `{1, 2, 3, 4}`) ?

Although these questions seem trivial at first sight but any comprehensive answers are welcome. Anyone using a package shouldn't bother his head about Mathematica subtleties.

Comment: Can you simplify this question to its essence?  Try removing a lot of the physics, and the extraneous information.

Comment: You're probably best of not using `Part` at all. Define tensor objects which take indices, so `T[m,-n]` can display as `T^m_n` but if you give an index in the appropriate range, then it will look at the appropriate [DownValues](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DownValues.html) to see if there is anything associated with it. E.g. `T[0,0] = f[r]` is the energy density. Look at how the [xCoba](http://www.xact.es/Documentation/HTML/HTMLLinks/xCobaDoc.nb_2.html) part of [xAct](http://www.xact.es/) deals with components. (Most abstract matrix and tensor implementations work this way...)

Comment: This very useful article, **Using zero based arrays and lists in Mathematica** by [Nasser M. Abbasi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/765271/nasser-m-abbasi), who cleverly uses the Notation package to do something similar, might be of interest.  It is available [here](http://12000.org/my_notes/using_zero_index_in_Mathematica/index.htm) (Nasser's Website). [I am sure Nasser has an answer on SO about this, but I cannot locate it]

Comment: @Simon, Thanks for an alternative to tackle the problem.  I knew about xAct bundle, but I thought there was a more straigthforward solution.

Comment: @TomD, Thanks for a reference to Nasser M.Abbasi's article

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) Mathematica list indexing, via Part ( [[]] in more common notation) starts at 1. The 0 part is the head of the expression.

(2) Can define a "function" that takes the indices you want and adds 1 to each.

```
xx = {t, x, \[Theta], \[Phi]}; 
g = {{-E^(2*\[Nu][x]), 0, 0, 0}, {0, E^(2*\[Lambda][x]), 0, 0}, {0, 
    0, x^2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, x^2*Sin[\[Theta]]^2}}; 

gg[indices___] := g[[Sequence @@ ({indices} + 1)]]
```

Examples:

```
In[121]:= gg[0]
Out[121]= {-E^(2*\[Nu][x]), 0, 0, 0}

In[123]:= gg[2, 2]
Out[123]= x^2
```

(3) See (2) for a possible approach. See (1) to understand that Part is NOT the direct way to go.

Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: But according to documentation of Table it says: Table[expr,{i,Subscript[i, min],Subscript[i, max]}]
starts with i=Subscript[i, min].   So there seems no reason not to start i at 0.

Comment: You can create Table with any set of indices. But you cannot index via Part that way. The elements begin at part 1, etc.

Comment: @Harmon I believe you are confusing the index used to create the expression `V` and the index of the parts of the expression itself.  One can write `a = Table[i^2, {i, -4, 5}]` which starts with `(-4)^2` but the resulting list is just a list.  If you want to preserve a different correlation, you could use something like `b = Table[i -> i^2, {i, -4, 5}]` and then extract your part with `-4 /. b` which yields `16`.

Answer (score 11):

It is not my intention to be trivial or flippant about your concern, however I am having some trouble understanding the significance of your dilemma.  *Mathematica*, or more specifically `Part` indexes from one, and that is simply the way it is.  I am tempted to say use e.g. `V[[n+1]]` but I have to suppose you have already considered this.

---

Index `0` is reserved for the head of the expression.  While it is far from standard, the flexibility of *Mathematica* syntax actually allows for this construct:

```
V = 0[-1, -2, -3][{1, 0, -1, -2}, {2, 1, 0, -1}, {3, 2, 1, 0}];

V[[0,2]]
```

```
-2
```

This works because the heads themselves contains your data.  This is not advisable, but presented for academic interest.

---

In specific answer to your first question, and for explanation of the trick above, you must be familiar with *Mathematica* heads.  Every expression conceptually has a head.  In the expression `a + b` the head is `Plus`.  In `{1, 2, 3}` it is `List`.  You can see these written out by using `FullForm`.  Other types also have conceptual heads, even if they are not explicit in `FullForm`.  You can determine these using `Head`.  For example:

```
Head /@ {"abc", 1, Pi, 3.14, 1/2}
```

```
{String, Integer, Symbol, Real, Rational}
```

The `Part` syntax `[[0, 0]]` asks for the head of the head.  In the case of your array, which is a list of lists, the head is `List`, and the head of `List` itself is `Symbol`, which defines its type.

---

In reply to your second question, I would define a new Part function that indexes from zero.

```
myPart[x_, spec__] := Part[x, ##] & @@ ({spec} /. n_Integer :> n + 1)

V = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

myPart[V, 0, 0]
```

```
1
```

This also works with `Span`:

```
myPart[V, All, 0 ;; 1]
```

```
{{1, 2}, {4, 5}, {7, 8}}
```